# Rxjs - await inside of subscribe function

Tags: rxjs

How can I use await inside of an rxjs subscribe function, and have the promise resolve before continuing to handle events?

Here is a codepen: https://codepen.io/parliament718/pen/YzKqMJB

```
let state = { end: 10 };


interval(500).pipe(
    switchMap(async (data) => {
       console.log('new quote', data);

       if(data >= state.end) {
          state.end = await getData();

         console.log('get new end', state);
       }
    })
  )
  .subscribe()


async function getData() {
  return await new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => { resolve(state.end + 10) }, 600);
  });
}
```

The output is:

```
new quote 10
new quote 11
new end {end: 20}
new quote 12
new end {end: 30}
new quote 13
```

Where as I need to the output to be:

```
new quote 10
new end {end: 20}
new quote 11
new quote 12
new quote 13
```

The problem is "quote 11" fires before the getData promise resolves, causing getData to be called twice.

I thought switchMap was supposed to handle this situation.

Comment: [`switchMap`](https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/switchMap) will resolve an *observable* returned from the project function before continuing, not a promise.

Comment: `switchMap` actually unsubscribes the inner observable. `concatMap` is the one that caches emissions, and `exhaustMap` if you want to ignore outer emissions until the inner observable completes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Part of the problem is that you're trying to use a Promise in an Observable context. `switchMap` unsubscribes from any inner Observable when the external Observable emits, which is still not your desired behaviour. You need something along these lines:

```js
interval(500).pipe(
  concatMap(data => { // concatMap places new emissions in a queue, waiting until each inner Observable completes before emitting the next one
    console.log('new quote', data);

    if(data >= state.end) {
      return from(getData()); // creates an Observable which completes when the Promise resolves
    } else {
      return of(false); // allows us to filter out states where getData isn't called
    }
  }),
  filter(newEnd => !!newEnd), // ignore anything where getData isn't called
  tap(newEnd => { // only if getData was called
    state.end = newEnd;
    console.log('get new end', state);
  })
).subscribe();
```

Using `concatMap` caches the next value, so the comparison in each step only takes place *after* the previous one is finished.